# How to append arbitrary (possibly compound) ordering sequence to an IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq

I want append an arbitrary sequence of one-or-more ordering clauses (which are declared using expressions rather strings via dynamic linq) to an IQueryable.  How might this be done?

Here's the crux of the problem:

```
private IOrderedQueryable<TProject> Demo<TSource, TProject>(
    IQueryable<TSource> query,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TProject>> project,
    Expression<Func<IQueryable<TProject>, IOrderedQueryable<TProject>>> order
) {
    var projection = query.Select(project);
    //??? How to combine project and order as an expression tree
    var orderedProjection = order.Compile()(projection);
    //??? rather than a compiled delegate (as shown here)
    return orderedProjection;
}
```

Some more context (which as noted by khellang doesn't compile):

```
private class ProjectOrder<TProjection> {
    public Expression<Func<Part, TProjection>> Projection { get; set; }
    public Expression<Func<IQueryable<TProjection>, IOrderedQueryable<TProjection>>> Ordering { get; set; }
}

private class PartFilters {
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string[] PartNumbers { get; set; }
    public int[] PartTypes { get; set; }
    //....
}

private IOrderedQueryable<TProjection> Fetch<TProjection>(ProjectOrder<TProjection> projectOrder, PartFilters filters) {
    var baseQuery = _db.Part_Parts;

    //append where predicates to baseQuery based on filters

    var projection = baseQuery.Select(projectOrder.Projection);

    //??? How to combine projection and ordering as
    var orderedProjection = projectOrder.Ordering.Compile()(projection);
    //??? an expression tree rather than a compiled delegate

    return orderedProjection;
}

private void TestFetch(PartFilters filters) {

    Expression<Func<Part, PartDescription>> projection = _ => new PartDescription() {
        PartNumber = _.PartNumber,
        Description = _.Description
    };

    //Arbitrary sorting expression, multiple clauses, could use base classes or joined entities
    //via navigation properties
    Expression<Func<IQueryable<PartDescription>, IOrderedQueryable<PartDescription>>> order =
                        q => q.OrderBy(_ => _.PartNumber.Length).ThenBy(_ => _.PartNumber);

    var projectOrder = new ProjectOrder<PartDescription>() {
        Projection = projection,
        Ordering = order
    };

    Fetch<PartDescription>(projectOrder, filters);
}
```

Comment: It's very hard to grok what you're trying to accomplish here. It's just a bunch of weird code (not compiling) and a _very_ vague question...

Comment: It's hard to understand what you are after here.  Can you describe what you want for the results to be, and maybe include some code or pseudo code that demonstrates how the caller would use your code?

Comment: Is the issue just that you want to be able to pass an expression that is used to form the orderby?

Comment: Precisely. I would like to pass a predefined expression representing an ordering sequence.  E.g., OrderBy(_ => Field1).ThenBy(_ => _.BaseClassField2).ThenByDescending(_ => NavProp1.NavProp2.Field) and apply it to an IQueryable.

Comment: @Servy beat me to it (upvote)  IQueryables are composable, which means that even if you are querying a database with EntityFramework, the query will be resolved into a query with an order by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason for the third parameter to be an expression at all.  It can just be a regular delegate.

The whole point here is that executing `order` is not actually performing the ordering. Executing `order` is *manipulating the expression of your query*.  You don't need an `Expression` that represents how to manipulate your `Expression` object.  You can just do it.

```
private IOrderedQueryable<TProject> Demo<TSource, TProject>(
    IQueryable<TSource> query,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TProject>> projection,
    Func<IQueryable<TProject>, IOrderedQueryable<TProject>> order) 
{
    return order(query.Select(projection));
}
```

And voila, you have a method that builds the query given the projection and ordering.

Comment: Perfect!  I had conceptual misunderstanding and supposed that this approach was using a delegate to manipulate the materialized IQueryable in memory.